# Securing URLs Using Spring Security: Multiple Different Roles

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have setup a login/registration webapp by following this [tutorial](https://hellokoding.com/spring-boot/security-login-mysql-jsp/). Now I want to implement it so that users of different roles are taken to different directories (i.e. /admin/**). I have modified my configuration of the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/registration").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/sales/**").hasRole("SALES")
                .antMatchers("/production/**").hasRole("PRODUCTION")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login.html?error=true")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
```

And I modified the UserController and added the following:

```
    @Controller
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private SecurityService securityService;

    @Autowired
    private UserValidator userValidator;

    @GetMapping("/registration")
    public String registration(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("userForm", new User());

        return "registration";
    }

    @PostMapping("/registration")
    public String registration(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        userValidator.validate(userForm, bindingResult);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }

        userService.save(userForm);

        securityService.autoLogin(userForm.getUsername(), userForm.getPasswordConfirm());

        return "redirect:/home";
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login(Model model, String error, String logout) {
        if (error != null)
            model.addAttribute("error", "Your username and password is invalid.");

        if (logout != null)
            model.addAttribute("message", "You have been logged out successfully.");

        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping({"/admin/home"})
    public String admin_home(Model model) {
        return "home";
    }
    
    @GetMapping({"/sales/home"})
    public String sales_home(Model model) {
        return "home";
    }
    
    @GetMapping({"/production/home"})
    public String production_home(Model model) {
        return "home";
    }
    
    
}
```

Now after logging in I get a Whitelabel error page : There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available.

I created the home.jsp pages in the individual sub folders that I created. Also, after login it still goes to "/" instead of i.e "/admin/". Where can I change the fact that different roles will take users to a different page upon login? Can I put jsp pages in a folder in webapp? Is the position of my jsp right? It is currently (the webapp folder):
webapp

- admin
- sales
- production
- resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to control the redirect of the user upon login through a `SuccessHandler` class like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String redirectUrl = null;
        
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();
        for (GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority : authorities) {
            System.out.println("role " + grantedAuthority.getAuthority());
            if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("SALES")) {
                redirectUrl = "/sales/home";
                break;
            } else if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("ADMIN")) {
                redirectUrl = "/admin/home";
                break;
            } else if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("PRODUCTION")) {
                redirectUrl = "/production/home";
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("redirectUrl " + redirectUrl);
        if (redirectUrl == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        new DefaultRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, redirectUrl);
    }
}
```

As far as I have figured out I cannot put jsps into sub folders in the one that I define in application.properties.